# How to find data with specific tags in Python using requests module?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-3.11

This is the current HTML part that I need to get something from.

```
<table class="table table-hover sortable-theme-minimal table-heatmap" data-sortable="">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>
   </th>
   <th>
    Price
   </th>
   <th>
   </th>
   <th>
   </th>
   <th data-heatmap="1" data-heatmap-limit="5" style="text-align: center;cursor:pointer;">
    Day
   </th>
   <th data-heatmap="1" data-heatmap-limit="20" style="text-align: center;cursor:pointer">
    Month
   </th>
   <th data-heatmap="1" data-heatmap-limit="100" style="text-align: center;cursor:pointer">
    Year
   </th>
   <th class="hidden-xs" style="text-align: center;">
    Date
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tr data-decimals="3" data-subscribe="CL1:COM" data-symbol="CL1:COM">
  <td>
   <a href="/commodity/crude-oil">
    Crude Oil
   </a>
  </td>
  <td id="p">
   82.86
```

I need to get that 82.86 number, but I can't seem to specify to the "tr data-decimals="3" data-subscribe="CL1:COM" data-symbol="CL1:COM"" line.

Here is my current code:

```
URL = "https://tradingeconomics.com/commodity/crude-oil"
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find("table", class_="table table-hover sortable-theme-minimal table-heatmap")
results1 = results.find("tr", text="data-symbol=\"CL1:COM\"")
print(results.prettify())
```

Is there a way to specify the "data-symbol" class and get the data from the id="p" td under it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Beautiful Soup, try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://tradingeconomics.com/commodity/crude-oil"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

target_tr = soup.find("tr", attrs={"data-symbol": "CL1:COM"})
price_td = target_tr.find("td", id="p")

price = price_td.get_text(strip=True)
print("Price:", price)
```

Also Selenium could prove useful..gl

Comment: I second this, don't do this to yourself with requests, just use beautifulsoup.

Comment: This worked. Thanks for introducing me to 'attrs'. Super useful.